# Does windows phone sdk support the ObjectDataProvider

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-phone-8

does Windows phone support the ObjectDataProvider, from Wpf?
I can't find a way to use it inside the xaml.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. This is part of System.Windows, and if you check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider(v=vs.110).aspx you can see which platforms are supported on the bottom of the page.